# How should I install and import simpletransformers?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I have been using the following conda & python verison:

conda version : 4.6.14

conda-build version : 3.17.8

python version : 3.7.3.final.0

I installed simpletransformers in the following manner:

```
conda create -n simpletransformers python pandas tqdm
conda activate simpletransformers

conda install pytorch cpuonly -c pytorch
conda install -c anaconda scipy
conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn
pip install transformers
pip install seqeval
pip install tensorboardx

pip install simpletransformers
```

After doing so, I've been trying to import the classification model without much luck:

```py
import simpletransformers
```

I get the following error:

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simpletransformers'*

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong? I'm using PyCharm as my IDE.

Comment: @karel it won't be a globally installed package if you follow my answer. During a `conda env create -f` transaction, Conda runs a copy of pip local to the env in order to install the pip dependencies in the env's `site-packages`. If you create the env with the YAML as indicated in the answer, and then add it with the "*Existing interpreter*" option, it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The [setup docs](https://github.com/ThilinaRajapakse/simpletransformers#with-conda) work for me on Mac and Ubuntu using Anaconda:

1. Install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) or Miniconda
2. Create a new virtual python 3.7 environment and install pandas and tqdm
   `conda create -n simplet python=3.7 pandas tqdm`
   `conda activate simplet`
3. PyTorch
   3 a. GPU (`use_cuda=True` in your model): `conda install pytorch cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch`
   3 b. CPU (`use_cuda=False` in your model): `conda install pytorch cpuonly -c pytorch`
4. If you want to use fp16 training on an NVIDIA GPU install [apex](https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex) (don't use `pip`)
5. Install simpletransformers.
   `pip install simpletransformers`

Answer (score 1):

If you have **pip** installed in your environment, just do hit a `pip install simpletransformers` in your terminal or If you're using jupyter notebook/colab, etc. then paste `!pip install simpletransformers` in your first cell and run it.

Then import simpletransformers

```
import simpletransformers
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the .whl file from "https://pypi.org/project/simpletransformers/#files"

- Open command prompt
- type `pip install "path/simpletransformers-0.13.2-py3-none-any.whl" and hit enter`
  Check whether the package gets installed.
  **Note that simpletransformers requires Python '>=3.6'**

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have a package that is not available via Anaconda Cloud, i.e., I have to install from PyPI or GitHub, then I **create a YAML environment definition for it**. This follows the best practices enumerated in "[*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)".

The advantage of a YAML is that it allows Conda to solve for everything at once and it lets one treat envs as immutable objects (i.e., if you need to alter the env, edit the YAML and recreate). This helps avoid the mess that inevitably seems to result from running a series of `conda install`, `pip install`, or `conda update` commands.

For me this is a multi-stage process, but it has been a reliable workflow for me:

## Workflow for Mixed Conda-PyPI Environments

1. Look at the `setup.py` or `requirements.txt` of the non-Conda package. [Here it is for simpletransformers](https://github.com/ThilinaRajapakse/simpletransformers/blob/0.13.2/setup.py#L24).
2. For each requirement, check Anaconda Cloud (or `conda search`) to see if it is available as a Conda package.
3. If it is available, add it to the YAML file as a (non-pip) dependency. This ensures that everything that can come from Conda does.
4. Also, keep track of the channels that these packages come from. Note, I will not use a private channel I am unfamiliar with. In this case `pytorch`, `conda-forge`, and `defaults` (i.e., `anaconda`) suffice.
5. Include the packages that are PyPI-only under the `pip` section of the YAML, including the main package of interest (i.e., `simpletransformers`). Technically, you don't need to include the other dependencies, since pip will pull them in automatically, but I like to keep them explicit so that if I ever update the YAML I might check again if someone ported the PyPI packages to Conda Forge.
6. Create the env using the YAML

   ```
   conda env create -n st_env -f simpletransformers.yaml
   ```
7. Check to see if any additional packages were implicitly pulled in as dependencies from PyPI, but were actually available through Conda. Edit the YAML to put these in the Conda dependencies section. In this case, `keras` is apparently also needed.
8. Remove the env and recreate using the updated maximally Conda version.
9. Most important: **never change the env except through editing the YAML**.

## YAML for SimpleTransformers Environment

**simpletransformers.yaml**

```
name: st_env
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pandas
  - tqdm
  - cpuonly
  - pytorch
  - transformers
  - scipy
  - scikit-learn
  - requests
  - tensorboardx
  - keras
  - pip
  - pip:
      - seqeval
      - simpletransformers
```

Install with

```
conda env create -n st_env -f simpletransformers.yaml
```